# UpdateListItems giving error while trying to update a list in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am trying to update a list using sharepoint list web services. But I am getting the following error

```
Results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
 <Result ID="1,Update">
  <ErrorCode>0x8102000a</ErrorCode> 
  <ErrorText>Invalid URL Parameter. The URL provided contains an invalid Command or Value. Please check the URL again.</ErrorText> 
  </Result>
  </Results>
```

Here is my code snippet

```
string strViewID = "{46FCE9EB-C789-430F-B1A3-9ACA41FE9BD9}";
            XmlDocument camlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode queryNode = camlDocument.CreateElement("Query");
            XmlDocument myListDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement batchXML = myListDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
            batchXML.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            batchXML.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
            batchXML.SetAttribute("ViewName", strViewID);

           batchXML.InnerXml = "<Method ID ='1' Cmd='Update'>" + "<Field Name='Title'>Z</Field>" +"<Field Name='Region'>West</Field>"+
               "<Field Name='Size'>Z</Field>" + "<Field Name='Sales'>Z</Field></Method>";    
              XElement sys = XmlElementToXelement(batchXML);
                XElement myListReturn = ws.UpdateListItems("{A30AFD47-7118-4904-A3B9-BCEFF7E3E203}", sys);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try adding the ID Column along with your other columns in Update and try again -

< Field Name='ID' > ID of field you intend to update

Comment: Sorry for the space in <Field Name='ID'>ID of field you intend to update</Field>